# Issue with Electron Quick Start Guide

Tags: electron

Bonjour
I use

- Win 10 (2004)
- node 12.16.3
- Chrome 85.0.4183.121
- Electron 10.1.5.
- npm 7.0.8

I follow instructions available here : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start
Everything works fine until paragraph : **Package and distribute the application**
Indeed, the command :

```
npx @electron-forge/cli import
```

returns errors

```
PS C:\Users\phili\Documents\Temp\TestElectron2> npx @electron-forge/cli import
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\phili\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-08T10_52_07_011Z-debug.log
```

When I open the log file here is what I see

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   '@electron-forge/cli',
0 verbose cli   'import'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.0.8
2 info using node@v15.1.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\phili\Documents\Temp\TestElectron2\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\phili\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\phili\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session ab6a58cdc10c9f54
20 timing npm:load Completed in 19ms
21 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@electron-forge%2fcli 1749ms (from cache)
22 timing command:exec Completed in 1768ms
23 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
23 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\exec.js:241:23)
23 verbose stack     at exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\exec.js:158:15)
24 verbose cwd C:\Users\phili\Documents\Temp\TestElectron2
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "@electron-forge/cli" "import"
27 verbose node v15.1.0
28 verbose npm  v7.0.8
29 error could not determine executable to run
30 verbose exit 1
```

I believe this is a beginner's issue.
Can one of you guide me on the right path?

Best regards, 40tude

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same issue. I ended up just installing `electron-forge` and then running `import` without `npx`.

```
npm i -g @electron-forge/cli

electron-forge --version
6.0.0-beta.54

electron-forge import
```

Comment: I was actually able to get the tutorial command of `npx @electron-forge/cli import` to work after I updated my `npm` version with `npm install -g npm@latest`. (6.14.8)

Answer (score 6):

Just to confirm; I was facing the same issue. As @AndyL has pointed out updating the `npm` version using `npm install -g npm@latest` did the trick

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve it by:

```
npm add --include=dev @electron-forge/cli
npx electron-forge import
```

---

*update*: 
 replaced `--dev` with `--include=dev` as `--dev` is now deprecated (ref.: comment from [@ManuelMB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64737348/issue-with-electron-quick-start-guide/65695010?noredirect=1#comment117763312_65695010))

Comment: This also works for me, but I got this warning in the first command:

Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--include=dev` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **NodeJS** version (i had an old version and the same issue).

Only fix npm or try to install with `npm i -g @electron-forge/cli` won't work.

In my case I had to **update NodeJS** too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

I updated my npm (`$ npm install -g npm@latest`), and then, following the docs for NPM 7 here: https://www.electronforge.io/import-existing-project, the following two commands seemed to work  (from project root):

```
$ npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli

$ npm exec --package=@electron-forge/cli -c "electron-forge import"
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
npm add --dev @electron-forge/cli
./node_modules/.bin/electron-forge import
```